# Made oven ghee - what is the liquid at the top of my cold ghee?

Tags: butter, indian-cuisine, ghee

Yesterday I made ghee in the oven by cooking sweet butter for 2hrs in the oven at low temp.  I filtered the resulting liquid through cheese cloth and let the resulting clear liquid sit overnight.

Today, the ghee has congealed into a solid, as it should.  However, on top of it is an oily liquid.  I poured some into a glass and added water, and the two liquids don't mix, so it's not water left over from the butter (good news).  Still, I'm confused why I don't end up with a uniform material.

Answer (score 1):

Some butter is mixed with sunflower oil in order to make it more spreadable. Have you checked the ingredients list (if there is one) on the butter?

Comment: That was pure butter from pastured cows.

Comment: In the US at least, such a product would have to be labeled a "spread" or something other than butter...

Answer (score -1):

Whatever it is, it is no good.

Since it is congealed, it should be a snap to remove, allowing you to carry on with your life, your mind at rest.

Comment: I just think it's different types of oils which have different properties. Oils congeal at various temperatures depending on their makeup. I am suspecting two different types of oils were in the butter.. Do check the ingredient list in the butter.